# BigQuery duplicate table prefix name

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables on BigQuery, which are `log_` and `log_history_`, with serveral dates.

I want to query data from only `log_` with all date.

```
SELECT id, data FROM log_*
```

but it also queries data from `log_history_`.
I can’t change table name.
What should I do to get data from `log_` table only ?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `*` at the end?

Comment: The table name is like log_20180117, log_20180116, ... I want to select data from all date so I use wildcard character (i.e log_*)

Comment: You said you had two tables only...

Comment: Will `log_2*` do fine? (I.e. no tables from previous millennium.)

Comment: Sorry, I mean 2 types of table: log_*, log_history_*

Comment: yes, I also think about it. However I wonder is there another way better than that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use **Standard SQL**, you can do the following:

```
SELECT id, data FROM log_*
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX NOT LIKE '\\_history\\_%'
```

note that `\\_` is escape sequence for underscore in BigQuery.